# CodeIgniter Internal Server Error in Subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have deployed a website that uses CodeIgniter (`http://www.myexample.com/`) in the main `public_html` folder. In order to remove `index.php` from URL this has the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|css|app|favicon\.ico|uploads|thumbs|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Now, I've created a sub-domain where I've deployed the same website in order to have a development environment (`http://dev01.myexample.com/`). I’ve copied the whole website in the folder `public_html/dev01`. However, when I try to go to the website I'm getting an Internal Server Error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and
>   was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at
>   webmaster@dev01.myexample.com to inform them of the time this error
>   occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server
>   error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered
>   while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I know this is related to the `.htaccess` settings. However I'm not able to determine why this error is happening.

So far I've tried erasing `.htaccess` in both folders, or copying the `.htaccess` in both website folders. And also tried the following in the subdomain `.htaccess` file using relative path:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|css|app|favicon\.ico|uploads|thumbs|assets|robots\.txt)***
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dev01/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

point your sub domain to dev01 directory through cpanel and use the same htaccess as your live project

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|css|app|favicon\.ico|uploads|thumbs|assets|robots\.txt)***
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dev01/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

if you have put above htaccess code in dev01 directory it look for dev01 directory inside dev01 use this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|css|app|favicon\.ico|uploads|thumbs|assets|robots\.txt)***
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks umefarooq. However, I've had pointed my subdomain to the dev01 folder alreay. And I have tested both options of .htaccess code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /your_folder_or_project_nmae
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```